# Why is it legal to call a method that takes Any without any argument?

Tags: scala

Let alone why it's legal, why does this even return true

```
scala> class Bla { 
    def hello(x: Any): Boolean = x.toString.length == 2 
}
defined class Bla

scala> new Bla().hello() 
res0: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running with -deprecation gives this

```
scala> scala> class Bla { 
  def hello(x: Any): Boolean = x.toString.length == 2 
}
defined class Bla

scala> new Bla().hello()
<console>:13: warning: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: leaky (Object-receiving) target makes this especially dangerous.
        signature: Bla.hello(x: Any): Boolean
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: Bla.hello((): Unit)
       new Bla().hello()
                      ^
res0: Boolean = true
```

What the warning message means is:

`hello()` is interpreted as `hello(())`
and since `().toString = "()"`, the method returns `true`.

Comment: I don't know why you have to run it with `-deprecation` to see that. My version just prints it by default. Scastie will also whine at you if you do that.  Update `scala` maybe?

Comment: I'm on scala version 2.11.11. Perhaps it shows that by default on 2.12?

Comment: It definitely does show the warning by default on 2.12.4 (I still didn't upgrade to 2.12.5, hmm...).